# Determine $[F(a):F]$ if $a\in K$ has $k$ distinct images under Galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Suppose that $K/F$ is Galois extension and $a \in K$ has exactly $k$ distinct images under $Gal(K/F)$. Show that $[F(a):F]=k$.

My guess is that the images of $a$ form a basis of $F(a)$ over $F$. But I don't know how to show that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\;K/F\;$ is Galois it is then separable, so $\;a\;$ has as many conjugates as its minimal polynomial's degree.